# PancakeSwap Approve error 401

Tags: pancakeswap

I'm trying to use the contract approve function, but I have this 401 error :

> events.js:352
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
> Error: Unexpected server response: 401
> at ClientRequest. (H:\bot\pancake-swap\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:604:7)
> Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
> at abortHandshake (H:\bot\pancake-swap\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:731:15)
> at ClientRequest. (H:\bot\pancake-swap\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:604:7)

Does someone know what's wrong?

Comment: get the transaction hash and `debug.traceTransaction()` to find out whats wrong

Comment: What's the code you are using?

Comment: All I do is :
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider('wss://apis.ankr.com/wss/XXX/YYY/binance/full/main');

Comment: @user78481 That isn't the whole code. I would ask ankr.com perhaps it is something in their end.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I am facing the same error.

Comment: Hi Kristjan,
I have no idea what the problem was, but I succeeded in changing from Ankr to Moralis if I remember correctly.